# Tweak UI Navigation on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have a problem with a navigation bar in iOS 11. 
I use this code:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].prefersLargeTitles = YES;
```

...to set a new style for my app. It works well untill a user pull to refresh on the table view; then it breaks.

This is *before* pull-to-refresh:

[image]

...and this is _after:

[image]

Note: I use the table view controller's built-in pull-to-refresh control.

I searched for a solution but it still eludes me. If someone knows how to fix this please drop some advice.

Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Did you try to enable in your `.storyboard` Safe Area Guides (you can do it by going into "File Inspector" -> "Use Safe Area Layout Guides")? It solved similar problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have catch this bug too, and we have found the solution.

**You must constraint your UITableView to superview** (contentView of your view controller), after that large title and all related views  starts to work correct.

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I do not claim this is the solution for every situation the error occurs in, setting the navigationBar's `isTranslucent` property to true (which is also the default value) fixed the problem for me.

If you want to keep your navigation bar non-translucent you can use the following code:

```
navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
```