# Prefer Large Titles and RefreshControl not working well

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uirefreshcontrol

I am using this [tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-pull-to-refresh-to-a-table-view-or-collection-view) to implement a pull-to-refresh behavior with the `RefreshControl`. I am using a `Navigation Bar`. When using normal titles everything works good. But, when using "Prefer big titles" it doesn't work correctly as you can see in the following videos. Anyone knows why? The only change between videos is the storyboard check on "Prefer Large Titles".

[image: With "Prefer big titles"]
[image: With normal title]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347770/341994

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the end what worked for me was:

- In order to fix the RefreshControl progress bar disappearing bug with large titles:

  ```
  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
  ```
- In order to fix the list offset after `refreshcontrol.endRefreshing()`:

  ```
  let top = self.tableView.adjustedContentInset.top
  let y = self.refreshControl!.frame.maxY + top
  self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -y), animated:true)
  ```

Comment: If you have opaque  tab bar and the self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true makes everything go under the tab bar and you don't want this behavior then you can add 'self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.top'

Comment: First part helped me!

Comment: Check if you have any missing call of tableView.reloadData() before fixing the list offset, e.g. if you update tableHeaderView, you should call reloadData() immediately after it.

Answer (score 50):

I'm having the same problem, and none of the other answers worked for me.

I realised that changing the table view top constraint from the **safe area** to the **superview** fixed that strange spinning bug.

Also, make sure the constant value for this constraint is 0 .

[image: if using storyboard]

Comment: Was struggling since morning, this is the only solution that worked for me(iOS 12.1). Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too, got 1 week to find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked for me too! I had this bug for about a year

Comment: combine it with:      tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always

Comment: this issue still exists

Comment: I love you man <3

Answer (score 8):

If you were using `tableView.tableHeaderView = refreshControl` or `tableView.addSubView(refreshControl)` you should try using `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

Answer (score 4):

It seems there are a lot of different causes that could make this happen, for me I had a TableView embedded within a ViewController. **I set the top layout guide of the tableview to the superview with 0**. After all of that still nothing until I wrapped my RefreshControl end editing in a delayed block:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I had to go with this solution which does feel a bit hacky. I did get away with reducing + 1.0 down to + 0.2

Answer (score 3):

The only working solution for me is combining [Bruno's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54629641/2199288) with this line of code:

`tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always`

Comment: Thank you! Without this line of code, Bruno's suggestion causes an issue with `UIScrollView.scrollsToTop`. (Note: You can also set this in IB in the Size Inspector pane.)

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem. Call refreshControl endRefreshing before calling further API.

```
refreshControl.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(refreshData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func refreshData(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.model.loadAPICall {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did use OperationQueue and dependency between operations and it works good

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me using XIBs was Bruno's one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54629641/2178888

However I did not want to use a XIB. I struggled a lot trying to make this work by code using AutoLayout.

I finally found a solution that works:

```swift
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let tableView = UITableView()
        //configure tableView
        self.view = tableView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and i fixed it by embedded my scrollView (or tableView \ collectionView) inside stackView, and it's important that this stackView's top constraint will not be attached to the safeArea view (all the other constraints can). the top constraint should be connect to it's superview or to other view.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for very long, the only working solution for me was adding refresh control to the background view of tableview.

```
tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

I fixed this by delaying calling to API until my collection view ends decelerating

#### Long Answer

I notice that the issue happens when refresh control ends refreshing while the collection view is still moving up to its original position. Therefore, I delay making API call until my collection view stops moving a.k.a ends decelerating. Here's a step by step:

1. Follow [Bruno's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54629641/617704)
2. If you set your navigation bar's translucent value to false (`navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`), then you will have to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` on your view controller. Otherwise, skip this.
3. Delay api call. Since I'm using `RxSwift`, here's how I do it.

```swift
collectionView.rx.didEndDecelerating
    .map { [unowned self] _ in self.refreshControl.isRefreshing }
    .filter { $0 == true }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // make api call
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

4. After API completes, call to

```swift
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

#### Caveat

Do note that since we delay API call, it means that this whole pull-to-refresh process is not as quick as it could have been done without the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no advice helped. But I found a solution that helped me. Setting the transparency of the navigation bar helped.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWQFB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Problem can be solved if add tableview or scroll view as root view in UIViewController hierarchy (like in UITableViewController)

```
override func loadView() {
    view = customView
}
```

where customView is UITableView or UICollectionView