# UIRefreshControl in a UIScrollView is not triggered when Large title is used

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

When i use large titles for the Navigation bar, the added UIRefresh control for the UIScrollView is not triggered when pulled down

```
{
    self.scrollView.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollView.refreshControl];
    // add target
}
```

**When i use normal small titles, it starts working by triggering the event**

**How to make it work with large titles?**

[image]

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708081/prefer-large-titles-and-refreshcontrol-not-working-good?

Comment: this issue is not about flickering, but about the issue that the refresh control action is not called at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and for me I could make it work by calling `scrollView.refreshControl.didMoveToSuperview()` in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Works... How did you find out?