# Manually refresh UIRefreshControl not visible when using `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles`

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol, preferslargetitles

I create a programmatically refresh on my table view using this code

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually() {
        if let scrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height), animated: true)
        }
        beginRefreshing()
        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

It works fine if `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false` but if it is true then the UIRefreshControl is not visible, see the output below

This is the result if `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

[image]

As you can see, after the view was load, it automatically spin the `UIRefreshControl`, because I call the `tableView.refreshControl?.beginRefreshingManually()` on `viewDidAppear`

And this is the result if `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

[image]

As you can see, it loaded the function that call on `refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)` but the spinning animation is not visible.

This is the code where I set up the navigation bar large title

```
    private func setupNaigationBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.firstLineHeadIndent = 10 // This is added to the default margin
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 25)!, .foregroundColor: Keys.primaryColor, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

My expected result was to see the `UIRefreshControl` even if `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` programatically (without even scrolled by user)

Comment: did you check this answer? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721036/7512091

Comment: @emrcftci yes, I already add `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` but nothing happened

Comment: try setting `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: @Andre3000 something worse happened, it now ignore it's superview, and UIRefreshControl still not showing